# Can I build webkit for ios without much porting?

Tags: ios, webkit

Webkit supports building for mac OSX, so if I want to build it for iOS, do I need to port many (or any) files for it - does webkit already have an iOS platform porting implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The WebKit team announced the ability to build for the iOS Simulator yesterday:

https://www.webkit.org/blog/3457/building-webkit-for-ios-simulator/